# Update libwebp podspec

Tags: cocoapods, webp, podspec

The libwebp [Podspec](https://cocoapods.org/pods/libwebp) is out of date for both 0.5.2 and 0.6.0 (6 weeks due)

I can submit the podspec updates, but I couldn't locate the original Podspec creator (It seems Google themselves do not maintain it).

Any way to contact to original Podspec creator to hand over responsibility or update the podspec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in cocoapods:

`pod trunk info <pod name>` will list the maintainer email (where the website does not)